# How to call a custom action result from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom ActionResult that I pass in a url string to and it will stream a file back to me. How would I call this from Javascript file? Since I have to pass a string I don't think I can use jQuery's `$.post()` or `.ajax()` methods but I could be wrong. I also can not use Razor's `@Html.ActionLink` method for reasons involving the ? Here is my code.

```
public class ReportResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly string _fileName;
    public ReportResult(string fileName)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var cd = new ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = _fileName,
            Inline = false
        };
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = cd.ToString();

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead(_fileName))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
        }            
    }
}
```

The Controller Method that references it.

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdf(string filePath)
{
    return new ReportResult(filePath);
}
```

Comment: You can't download a file over AJAX.  You need a regular link.

Comment: so would using `@Html.ActionLink("Download report", "GetPdf", new { filename = "http://some.url.toreport.pdf" })` be the only way to immediately start the download?

Comment: Or any other form of navigation.  It's a normal URL.  What problem are you having.

Comment: Couple things. first the url is dynamic so I need to be able to update it after certain events happen. Second using the ActionLinkMethod starts the download immediately where as just using the link will try to open it in the browser.

Comment: I still don't know what you're asking.  You can construct a URL to your action and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Using something like `var url = '@Url.Action("DownloadPdf",)'; ` in the js and passing that through `$.post()` ?

Comment: AJAX won't actually download a file.

Comment: It's so strange that doing it as @html.ActionLink will download but doing it as just an <a> tag with the href set to the link tries to open it first.

Comment: That should not be true; `ActionLink()` just emits an `<a>` tag.  You're probably using a different URL.

Comment: @SLaks thanks for the guidance figured out where I was going wrong in the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason why I was having issues with the file opening up in a window rather than downloading was due to the Controller and Action method part of the url string getting cut off before it was getting passed to `location.href` in the Javascript. Below is the new Javascript that will open the url and immediately download the PDF file.

```
location.href = "/Controller/DownloadPdf?filePath=" + pdfUrl;
```

Thanks to @SLacks in the comments for some guidance.